# sort lat long by location (top left, top right) using pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, geospatial

I would like sort a list of lat / long points that I have in pandas ordered by: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right.  Aka, top left to bottom right.

My 4 point collections are almost rectangles, but are still irregular.  I have many of them and my first idea `df.sort([objectid, lat, long] acceding = [True, True, False])` doesn't quite work.

[image]

All the SO posts I've looked through that are tagged as related take a veer off into advanced programming.  Maybe my search terms are off.  I was just hoping for a sorting method that fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an interview question I had. My approach, which was accepted, was to find the degree from the origin of each point. After you have each degree, it's pretty straight forward to organize `65` < `76` < `76` <`90`.

Since this is a thorough implementation, I would reccomend making a class, let's call it "euclideanPoint". Each euclideanPoint has two attributes a Pair (for the actual coordinates) and a degree. Then you can [override the < operator and the equality](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) operator (by definining special methods in the class you're writing, i.e., methods whose names start and end with two underscores).

From there organizing your points using any data structure will be straight forward.

[Here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/operatoroverloading1.txt)'s another article on operator overloading in python.

Please let me know if you have any questions!